# Is there any need to test c# winform in different OS version?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have made windows application in visual studio 2010 in windows 7.

Will it work properly in other OS version (like windows XP, windows 8, etc..)?

I have used third party DLL as reference for HID connection in application.

If there are c# controls which will behave differently depend on OS version, then please give list of them with details.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You should test your software.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no list of such things. If you want to support Windows XP, you must test on Windows XP. Same for Windows 8, Vista, 10, etc. Be aware that depending on your software the list of platforms and configurations to test on might be **huge**. Visual Studio 2010? Most likely not one of the more recent .NET versions then, so what about High DPI monitors? Does your application scale correctly? Does it function without administrator user? Does it properly require .NET to be installed during installation? Does it **look** OK on all themes?

Comment: In general WinForms stuff if pretty solid on different versions. The things you should be concerned about is support for the .Net Framework version you are using. And also you should check 3rd party library support for different OS systems... they will be your biggest problem. It also really all depends on what your application actually does

Comment: You should also test early and often with different Windows themes. It's easy to create UI that breaks, or at best looks horrible, with a different font size, colors, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test on all the platforms you intend to support. Different O/S versions are, well, different (otherwise what's the point of them?), so you can't assume it will work the same way on each version. You may even find that things like the Service Pack version have an effect, or the version of other libraries available on the system (e.g. .NET framework in your case) can have an effect.

So, you should decide what platforms, with what minimum specs, you can support (from a technical point of view) *and* which of those platforms you are willing to put the time, effort and cost into supporting, for what period of time, and then plan to test thoroughly on all those platforms. And then repeat for each release of your software (so you might want to outline the support lifetime of each release in advance, so customers are prepared for when they need to upgrade).